# Problem is sending/receiving video file data using peer.js connection.send method

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, webrtc, peerjs

So, I am building a simple website, in which multiple peers can enter a particular dashboard with a unique id, and when one sends a video file that video starts streaming for other peers in the same dashboard.
I am using Express.js , socket.io, peerjs for this purpose. I want to send data over the WebRTC stream.

This is my server side code

```js
// Creating a express server
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server); // Passing the server created to socket.io 
const { v4: uuidV4 } = require('uuid')

// Set up Express.js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(`/${uuidV4()}`)
});

app.get('/:dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard', { dashboardId: req.params.dashboard })
})

// Set up Socket.io
io.on('connection', socket => {
  // Server starts listening for connections
  // Maintaining a dictionary for mapping userId for a particular dashboardId
  socket.on('join', (dashboardId, userId) => {
    socket.join(dashboardId)
    // Tell that another peer has joined
    console.log(userId)
    socket.broadcast.emit('userJoined',{userId:userId})
  })
})

// Start the server
const port = 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

This is my client side code

```js
const socket = io('/');
const peer = new Peer(undefined, {
  host: '/',
  port: '3001'
});

peer.on('open', function (id) {
  const CHUNK_SIZE = 5120; // 5KB
  socket.emit('join', DASHBOARD_ID,id);
  socket.on('userJoined',(userId)=>{
    console.log(userId)
    const conn = peer.connect(userId.userId);
    conn.on('open', function () {
      console.log('Connected to peer: ' + conn.peer);
      const video = document.getElementById('videoPlayer');
      const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
      const sendButton = document.getElementById('sendButton');
      sendButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        const file = fileInput.files[0];
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
          const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;
          const totalChunks = Math.ceil(arrayBuffer.byteLength / CHUNK_SIZE);
          let offset = 0;
          let chunkIndex = 0;
          while (offset < arrayBuffer.byteLength) {
            const chunk = arrayBuffer.slice(offset, offset + CHUNK_SIZE);
            const data = { chunk, name: file.name, totalChunks, chunkIndex };
            console.log('Sending chunk ' + (chunkIndex + 1) + ' of ' + totalChunks);
            conn.send(data);
            offset += CHUNK_SIZE;
            chunkIndex += 1;
          }
        };
      });

      let videoData = new Uint8Array();

      conn.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('Received chunk ' + (data.chunkIndex + 1) + ' of ' + data.totalChunks);
        videoData.set(data.chunk, data.chunkIndex * CHUNK_SIZE);
        if (data.chunkIndex + 1 === data.totalChunks) {
          const videoBlob = new Blob([videoData], { type: 'video/mp4' });
          const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);
          video.src = videoURL;
          video.play();
        }
      });
    });
  })
});
```

In my ejs file , I just have a video html object. On doing console log, I am getting this

```html
{userId: '1b2879cf-9cf8-4b34-b2cf-9aa859abf43f'}
script.js:14 Connected to peer: 1b2879cf-9cf8-4b34-b2cf-9aa859abf43f
Sending chunk 1 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 2 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 3 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 4 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 5 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 6 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 7 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 8 of 183
script.js:30 Sending chunk 9 of 183
...
```

So the connection is getting established with the right peer, but it is not getting received, for the receiver peer the data chunks are not getting logged and video is not streaming.
I have been debugging this since long but cannot understand what is wrong, Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it by using data channels as a part of your webrtc connection. I think it will be a lot easier to achieve what you want.

So, basically, you create a webrtc connection and then add a data channel to it. Then, the connection gets established, you listen for that event and then start sending your file chunks over that data channel. On the other side, you listen for the new data channel event and then you listen for the new data chunk event on that data channel.

Data channel utilises the very same UDP connection that audio/video rTP is using but the connection is reliable (if a chunk gets lost, it will get retransmitted and that will be transparent to you).

This example shows this in action, but feel free to ask questions: https://webrtc.org/getting-started/data-channels Notice that these guys are sending text messages, but you can also send data blobs (image files, videos etc).

This example shows that but is a little more involved: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/datachannel/filetransfer/